# SMPS typical drain current when MOSFET goes to saturation

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

Here an old smps circuit which is very similar to mine. But the gate driving voltage seems to be very high in my opinion.

Q1. If the gate threshold of the MOSFET is 2-4V , will the 12-15V pulse train from the UC3844 drive the MPSFET into saturation ( Id > 20A) ?

Q2. R4 and G6 don't seem to reduce the input gate voltage, then what are their functions?

Q3. What is the expected Id (in mA, I feel it shouldn't be more than 50omA else the 2W Rs will burse) ?

Q4. The primary impedance of the pulse transformer reads 1M ohms on DDM. Can't find any reference on internet so far. IS it way too high?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Exactly as designed, The FET SHOULD ABSOLUTELY be in saturation. The current rate of rise is limited by the transformer N1 and detected as a voltage developed across R5 to detect the switchoff point.

Comment: [MOSFET linear and saturation regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaxmH.png) not to be confused with the saturation region of a BJT! @JackCreasey

Comment: @Andyaka. I'm not confused about BJT ...are you? This is a stock standard SMPS application with a well understood and documented driver. The FET will need to be in saturation with a low VDS when on. https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/UC3844-D.PDF  Look at Figure 16 to understand the current sensing if you are confused about the operating point.

Comment: @JackCreasey MOSFET saturation is one thing and MOSFET linear region (where it should be operating) is another.

Comment: @Andyaka. The operation in this SMPS is not in the linear mode. Perhaps some reading might help your understanding: http://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/SiteComm_sg/documents/Training_Tutorials/en528035.pdf

Comment: @JackCreasey you said in your comment "The FET SHOULD ABSOLUTELY be in saturation". That is plainly wrong. If it were a BJT (rather than a MOSFET) then you would be correct.

Comment: @AndyakaI stand by that point. The FET should absolutely be driven to saturation. Not sure why you think it should not. Now the drive is not instantaneous, so it does have a turn on time ...so it does have a transition (ns) me. But the design intent is to drive the device to its lowest possible on resistance ….by definition this is saturation.

Comment: @JackCreasey MOSFET saturation is not the area that it should be operating in when hard switching on. You are confused in the naming of this region. It is called the triode or linear region. Check on the internet and you'll see I'm right. For a BJT, operating when fully turned-on it's called the saturation region because it is the base that is saturated. For a saturated channel (MOSFET) it behaves as a constant current.

Comment: @Andyaka You misinterpreting the operation shown in the curves. In the saturation region the device is only able to operate successfully when the current is below the line shown at an particular drive voltage. The area below the line IS in saturation. Look at the Microchip document Page 9   ...I agree that the line shown in a FET Vds/Vgs/Ids graphs is a line of constant current ...but is does not represent thje operating line in an SMPS application where the objective is to achieve the lowest possible RDS(on). Below any particular VGS line is in saturation …..above it is in constant current.

Comment: I’m not getting anything mistaken. Saturation in a mosfet means channel saturation and constant current and NOT the correct region for lowest on resistance.

Comment: @JackCreasey your link has a BJT output , thus saturation term is correct, but not for FETs.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Which link shows a bjt?  ...I don't see it

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/UC3844-D.PDF fig16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the gate threshold of the MOSFET is 2-4V , will the 12-15V pulse
>   train from the UC3844 drive the MPSFET into saturation ( Id > 20A) ?

It will drive the MOSFET into the linear region where it acts like a low resistance on switch. 20 amps can only be drawn if the transformer primary current rises to that value and this seems very unlikely looking at the schematic because the core will very likely saturate. Vgs(th) must be significantly exceeded to operate the MOSFET correctly in this application.

> Q2. R4 and G6 don't seem to reduce the input gate voltage, then what
>   are their functions?

R4 is to prevent high surge current into the mainly capacitive impedance of the MOSFET gate-source region. It's a form of slew rate control that can be effectively used for reduction in EMI. R6 prevents the MOSFET gate floating and turning on the MOSFET should the driver IC (UC3844) go into a brown out situation.

> Q3. What is the expected Id (in mA, I feel it shouldn't be more than
>   50omA else the 2W Rs will burse) ?

I expect it'll be less than 1 amp but it all depends on the value (ambiguously marked as 0.17) and the switching frequency and the primary transformer inductance.

> Q4. The primary impedance of the pulse transformer reads 1M ohms on
>   DDM. Can't find any reference on internet so far. IS it way too high?

Sounds like it is broken. You should be able to measure a few ohms between the terminals of N1.

Comment: Thanks again. R6 to prevent floating gate seems nice. Rs value is 0.17 ohm , no ambiguous.